# How to add text to paragraphs on clicking button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a policy generator page. Where you input the text and get the output. But I'm facing the problem:
problem (I'm not able to generate multiple codes. Mean I want to generate privacy policy terms and conditions in different div areas eg:( `<p id="p2"><code class="generator__markup-generated"></code></p>`))

Here's my code

```js
    
           
                const generate = document.querySelector('.generate-markup');
    
                generate.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    const varName = document.querySelector('#company').value;
                    const idName = document.querySelector('#url').value;
                    const markupContainer = document.querySelector('.generator__markup-generated');
    //sample paragraph policy
                    const markup = `
                    ${varName} have a website ${idName} which you can use to generate policies.
    
        `;
    
                    markupContainer.textContent = markup;
                });
    
                function copyToClipboard(element) {
                    var $temp = $("<input>");
                    $("body").append($temp);
                    $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
                    document.execCommand("copy");
                    $temp.remove();
                }
```

```html
  
        <div class="generator__markup" style="font-size: 18px; text-align: center;"><label>Company Name:</label>&nbsp;<input id="company" type="text" />&nbsp;</div>
    
        <div class="generator__markup" style="font-size: 18px; text-align: center;"><label>Website Url:</label>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="url" type="text" />&nbsp;</div>
    
    
    
    
        <button class="generate-markup">Generate Code</button>
    
        </br>
        <div class="generator__markup">
            <h1 style="text-align: center;">Copy Your Page</h1>
    
            <p id="p2"><code class="generator__markup-generated"></code></p>
    
    
            <center>
                <button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p2')">Click To Copy</button></center>
```

please help in this thing

Comment: Just to be sure, when you click on generate code button, you want Privacy Policy, terms and conditions to be added with the existing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify HTML elements, you use the JavaScript DOM API.

It appears that the text for the policies is stored in the `markup` variable. We need to take this text and put it inside the element as `innerText`.

First, we need to get a reference to the DOM element. I see that you have selected the element using `querySelector` to grab a `class` attribute. This selects all elements with that class. You need to use an `id` attribute instead to select a single element. Let's assume you assign the `id` attribute of the paragraph to `generated-markup-paragraph`.

So, with this corrected code, we can now set the text of the paragraph:

```js
const markupParagraph = document.getElementById("generated-markup-paragraph");
markupParagraph.innerText = markup;
```

That code should go in the place of the `markupContainer.textContent = markup` line.